# Internal server on implements ShouldBroadcast

Tags: laravel, pusher

I make an event in laravel to make **web socket using pusher**, 
in `.env` I have setting *puser id* and *security*, already register in `app.php`, already setting in `bootstarp.js`, already setting *event* and `channel.php` but when I implement *ShouldBroadcast* it's getting an internal error

Here is event code:

```
namespace App\Events;
use App\Message;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NewMessage implements ShouldBroadcast //jika di nyalakan internal error
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Message $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('messages.'.$this->message->to);
    }
    public function broadcastWith(){
        return ['message'=>$this.message];
    }
}
```

and this is error in console log

```
app.js:279 POST http://localhost:8000/conversation/send 500 (Internal Server Error)
dispatchXhrRequest @ app.js:279
xhrAdapter @ app.js:118
dispatchRequest @ app.js:726
Promise.then (async)
request @ app.js:528
Axios.<computed> @ app.js:553
wrap @ app.js:1071
sendMessage @ app.js:1998
invokeWithErrorHandling @ app.js:50394
invoker @ app.js:50719
invokeWithErrorHandling @ app.js:50394
Vue.$emit @ app.js:52414
send @ app.js:2044
keydown @ app.js:48351
invokeWithErrorHandling @ app.js:50394
invoker @ app.js:50719
original._wrapper @ app.js:56072
app.js:653 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (app.js:653)
    at settle (app.js:899)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:166)
```

and channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('messages.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

Comment: Can you post the full error and the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using component then you should `npm run dev`
try using "channel" first , if its work then using private channel edit App\provider\BroadcastServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
{
    Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]);

    require base_path('routes/channels.php');
}
```

Comment: oh it is working replace auth:api with web.. thank u very much